# Updating a package while TeX Live is frozen

Tags: circuitikz, updating, tlmgr

I need to update my `circuitikz` version to `1.0`, but I got the following output from `tlmgr update --all`

```
TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

The output of `tlmgr info circuitikz` is the following

```
TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
package:     circuitikz
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Draw electrical networks with TikZ
longdesc:    The package provides a set of macros for naturally typesetting electrical and (somewhat less naturally, perhaps) electronic networks. It is designed as a tool that is easy to use, with a lean syntax, native to LaTeX, and directly supporting PDF output format. It has therefore been based on the very impressive pgf/TikZ package.
installed:   Yes
revision:    51071
sizes:       doc: 761k, run: 665k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 0.9.0
cat-date:    2019-05-10 14:19:41 +0200
cat-license: lpplgpl
cat-topics:  diagram-circ pgf-tikz
cat-contact-home: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz
cat-contact-support: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues
cat-contact-bugs: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues
collection:  collection-pictures
```

is there a way to update this package to 1.0 through command line, without having to manually download the `.sty` file and all that?

Comment: This is strange. So many cats. `cat-version`, `cat-date`, `cat-license`, ... I always thought the maintainer of circuitikz was a squirrel. ;-) BTW, AFAIK you can get the latest version of `circuitikz` also from [here](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/).

Comment: Yeah I know, but I wanted to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Did you try running with sudo as suggested in the message?

Comment: Hmmm... you something strange here. The frozen version should be 1.0.1. Have you tried `tlmgr update --self` before issuing `tlmgr update --all`?

Comment: Also, the error says that you have no write permission on `/usr/local/texlive/2019/...` --- this is strange. Maybe you need to use `sudo`? Which operating system is this?

Comment: The problem was not running those commands as admin. Issuing `sudo tlmgr update --self` and `sudo tlmgr update --all` worked, and I'm now running `v1.0.1` of circuitikz.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by using `sudo` as indicated in comments.